# DLL Caching Issue, Used By Another Process in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll

Of all the projects I have worked on I keep this this error below with multiple referenced projects.  I keep having to clean it and then build.  I feel like I am in Eclipse but this is happening in Visual Studio.  This has never happened before, any tips on what to check?

Error   53  Unable to copy file "C:\Development\Projects\Pearson\ARIES\Development\Projects\ARIES.Web.Models\bin\Debug\ARIES.Web.Models.dll" to "bin\ARIES.Web.Models.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\ARIES.Web.Models.dll' because it is being used by another process.  ARIES.Web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/40ed753e-47af-4638-8a72-1d607102a05c/)

Edit your project file and add this to the first PropertyGroup:

```
   <GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>true</GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>
```