# publish to IIS local folder without iisreset

Tags: iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2022

Every time I publish a blazor server app to a local folder,
I get an error (`Publish has encountered an error.`)

if I don't call
`iisreset` in advance

the `tmp` file with the error message says this:

> 12/21/2022 12:00:24 PM System.AggregateException: One or more errors
> occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException:
> Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.    --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.
> Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.
> Check the Output window for more details.
>
> ===================

and in the output window I see lots of errors like:

> Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file
> "...\WebUI\obj\Release\net7.0\PubTmp\Out\WebUi.dll" to
> "...\WebUi.dll". The process cannot access the file '...\WebUi.dll'
> because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Enable shadow copying https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/07/19/aspnetcore6-shaddow-copy-iis.html

Comment: According to these error messages, this may be an error of your local project, can you work normally locally?

Comment: @samwu locally it runs in iisexpress, when I run it from VS2022 (Ctrl + F5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [`Resource Monitor`](https://superuser.com/a/643312) to check which process is using the `WebUi.dll` file.

You can End Process to check whether it works. And if you think this file shouldn't been used when you build or deploy the project. You can try to add below code in your .csproj file. For more details, you can check [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7184645/7687666).

```
<GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>true</GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>
```

Comment: iisexpress.exe is using `webui.dll`

Comment: @buga Have you tried the `GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies=true` ? Does it useful to you ?

Comment: @buga According your description about using `ctrl+f5`, I suggest you upgrade the visual studio to latest version. I am using VS2022 (the latest version) and haven't seen the same issue.

Comment: will try `GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies` next time I'll have the chance, the `ResourceMonitor` trick was really helpful